# how to delete duplicates for multi-fields in a table?(mysql)

Tags: mysql

If a table is like this:

```
id | complains | zipcode
--------------------------
1  |  drinking |  10000
2  |  drinking |  10000
3  |  wasting  |  10000
4  |  wasting  |  10000
5  |  wasting  |  10000
6  |  wasting  |  10011
7  |  wasting  |  10011
```

I want to get just:

```
---------------
drinking  10000
wasting   10000
wasting   10011
---------------
```

How should I write a SQL query? I wrote like this, but update and select cannot be execute at same time in mySQL.

```
delete from table where id not in (select max(id) from table group by complains, zipcode)
```

Comment: Why delete rows instead of just selecting the data you want?

Comment: I create a new table and it solved. thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subselect to trick MySQL:

```
delete from table 
where id not in 
(
     select * from (select max(id) from table group by complains, zipcode) x
)
```